# Error: No provider for RouterStateSnapshot when using with CanLoad guard in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am trying to redirect the users to login page, if the user isn't logged in. Once the user logs, I want to take the user back to the previous page. But I am getting an error as `StaticInjectorError[RouterStateSnapshot]: NullInjectorError: No provider for RouterStateSnapshot!`.

Here's the code for the CanLoad functionality:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenGuardService implements CanLoad {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot) {}

  canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if(this.authService.doesTokenExist()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: this.snapshot.url }});
        return false;
      }
  }
```

and here's the code my Component

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/dashboard';
  }

onLoginFormSubmit() {
//Some success scenario
if(success) {
   this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
  }
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You most likely have solution to problem by now, did you mean to use CanActivate? CanLoad receives a Route https://angular.io/api/router/Route